# Loading data from database during application startup

Tags: java, spring

There is a table in DB(Oracle) which stores "code" and its "Description". I need to load this table data during my application startup and store it in a variable (probably a Map object) so that I can look up the description of the code for each request without hitting the DB for every request. What would be the best way to do this?

Application is a standalone Java application based on Spring framework.

Thanks.

Comment: Same way you perform all your other queries to the database. Which part is troubling you? --- Also, you might want to consider lazy loading, i.e. to not query the database until you need a description the first time.

Comment: well, the answer could be a bit complex, you can handle this in two ways "JDBC" and "Hibernate", we need more informations to answer properly.
take a look on "Prepared statement JDBC" probably is the easiest way then you can populate a map object from the prepared statement

Comment: Yes. I ll query the DB to fetch those data. I was looking more on the Spring configuration side to do this. Should I declare a bean and define a init-method which queries the DB and loads the data? or Is there any other better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Kishore check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that picks application startup method.
In spring you can implement `ApplicationListener` interface with `ApplicationReadyEvent` event.

At this point your application is ready to communicate with database
and will execute your code automatically.

```
@Component
public class AppBootstrapListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    //Inject Service or repository if you have.

    /**
    * Executes on application ready event
    * Check's if data exists & calls to create or read data
    */
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        // code here
    }

}
```

For any clearification add a comment

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but Spring events might help. For example, you can use ContextRefreshedEvent - this event is published whenever the Spring Context is started or refreshed.

Please check: [running-code-on-spring-boot-startup](https://springframework.guru/running-code-on-spring-boot-startup/) or [better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#annotation-driven-event-listener)